# Is it safe to use QRegExp object which is declared `static const`?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to optimize my code a bit and found that my usage of `QRegExp` does not involve any non-const methods of it:

- [int QRegExp::indexIn(const QString &str, int offset = 0, QRegExp::CaretMode caretMode = CaretAtZero) const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#indexIn)
- [QString QRegExp::cap(int nth = 0) const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#cap)

The code I have:

```
QString parse(const QString &data) {
    static const QRegExp DATA_REGEXP(QStringLiteral("^(\\w{4}) (\\w{4}) SN=(\\w*)"));

    if (DATA_REGEXP.indexIn(data) != -1) {
        const QString vendorId = DATA_REGEXP.cap(1);
        const QString modelId = DATA_REGEXP.cap(2);
        const QString serial = DATA_REGEXP.cap(3);

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

I wondered how could this be possible (having `const`-methods which actually change the object), looked over [the code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qregexp.cpp.html#_ZNK7QRegExp7indexInERK7QStringiNS_9CaretModeE) and found that even though the methods are declared as `const`, they operate on mutable (do not be confused with `mutable` keyword) private object inside (Qt uses PIMPL idiom). So now I wonder whether it is safe to call `indexIn` and `cap` on this `static const QRegExp` object or not? These methods do not seem to be reentrant as their usage from multiple threads will lead to changing shared memory, so I guess I have to use synchronization primitives, is that correct?

Comment: They may operate on a non-const object, but do they call any non-const members of that object? (and in a perfect world, all pimpls would use something like `propagate_const`).

Comment: @StoryTeller yes they do: they have QRegExpState::match call which is `non-const` on that object.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy This is a particular case of `QRegExp`, generally Qt classes use a d_func() function to access the pimpl pointer. This function has a const and a non const overload, making sure you do not use the pimpl pointer in a non const way inside a const function. You can take a look at the definition of `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE` to see for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case the [doc fo indexIn()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html#indexIn) states:

> Although const, this function sets matchedLength(), capturedTexts() and pos().

Clearly this means that `indexIn()` should not be const.

Other than this particular case, Qt classes do propagate const to their private pointers.

In your case, I would recommend using `QRegularExpression` as making a match does not modify the state of the regexp, but returns a `QRegularExpressionMatch` object.

Quoting again [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#notes-for-qregexp-users):

> The QRegularExpression class introduced in Qt 5 is a big improvement
>   upon QRegExp, in terms of APIs offered, supported pattern syntax and
>   speed of execution. The biggest difference is that QRegularExpression
>   simply holds a regular expression, and it's not modified when a match
>   is requested. Instead, a QRegularExpressionMatch object is returned,
>   in order to check the result of a match and extract the captured
>   substring. The same applies with global matching and
>   QRegularExpressionMatchIterator.
>
> Other differences are outlined below.

Answer (score 2):

All functions of QRegExp are *reentrant*, however they are not [*threadsafe*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html). So this code is fine if it will only ever run in a single thread.

If you want to call this function from multiple threads, you have two options:

- Create a [QMutex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html) (and possibly [QMutexLocker](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutexlocker.html)) to lock this block of code
- Do *not* make the `QRegExp` instance `static`, so different threads have different instances.
- Make the RegExp `thread_local` (as StoryTeller pointed out)

I would avoid the first option, since pausing threads is rarely a good idea.

Comment: You could make it `thread_local`... Depends if the cost of thread_local storage is comparable to creating `QRegExp`, of course.